# Workbook file after saving always causing git to detect changes even .gitattributes is added

Tags: excel, git, binary

I have workbook with extension "xlsm" put into repo.
What i am doing i am writing changes to it using apache poi code:

```
IDataObject dataObject = bundle.createDataObject(reportName, objectLocation, MIME_TYPE_EXCEL_OFFICIAL);
    try (OutputStream out = dataObject.getOutputStream();) {
        workbook.write(out);
    }
workbook.close();
```

or manually I am going, opening workbook, clicking ctrl + save.

My problem is that git always seeing this as change.

I added file .gitattributes and there put:

```
*.xlsm binary
*.xlsx binary
```

I put the file in the repo next to .git folder (which is hidden folder). Windows browser is saying that this a text file (without any extension).

What i did as next was to use these commands:
git rm --cached -r --> first one reset git index
git reset --hard --> second one is resetting whole data

The issue is that all the time git is showing after git status not commited files. It is always seeing the change into binary file which i do not want to have. It is making repo dirty.

Can anybody help? Why this is happening? What i am doing wrong?
Did anybody had similar issue with *.xlsm or *.xlsx files?

How to make them skipped by git? And why to use .gitattributes over to .gitignore?

Thans for help,
Michał